# two output files for two different tasks using same input file in hadoop

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

I am new to hadoop and so i have taken up tasks and i have a csv file and i want to find the names of visitors and names of visitee from the file which contains the data of a company.
here is my code which is used to find only visitors. My output has to be a file with top 20 visitors and the count of each and following it top 20 visitee with their count.
first name last name and mid name of visitor is in col 0,1,2 and that of visitee is in column 20.

```
package dataset;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

 public class Data {

  public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private Text word = new Text();

     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

         String[] str=value.toString().split(",");
         String wo=str[1]+" "+str[2]+" "+str[0];
     // System.out.println(str[0]);
      word.set(wo);
            context.write(word, new IntWritable(1));
         }

  } 

  public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

      TreeMap<IntWritable,Text> T=new TreeMap<>();
     public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
       throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         int sum = 0;
         for (IntWritable val : values) {
             sum += val.get();
         }
         T.put(new IntWritable(sum),new Text(key));
         if(T.size()>20)
         {
             System.out.println(T.firstKey());
             T.remove(T.firstKey());
         }
     }

     protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
     {

         for (IntWritable k : T.keySet()) {
             System.out.println(k);
                context.write(T.get(k),k);
     }
  }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Configuration conf = new Configuration();

         Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

     job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

     job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
     job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

     job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
     job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

     FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please clearly describe your desired results, then describe the problem and your question.

Comment: I hope it is clear now

Comment: Yes, your goal is very clear now.  What's the actual problem you're having; what is not working and what have you tried?

Comment: I tried outputting the visitors in one file when i tried displaying visitee (i used in the same mapper)  my file is getting overwritten. I just want to seperate it either in the same file or evn different would work.

Comment: Output file is defined by `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));`, which means you pass the name of the output directory to the job. By default, if the output directory exists, your Hadoop job will fail without overwriting it. Make sure that you check the output on HDFS, not on the local filesystem, and that you run the Hadoop in distributed mode